# Nodejs Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 on nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

when I try to connect my system to nodeJs sockets (socket.io) I'm getting an error saying

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://mysite.co/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=SkcmTj6P8_qAL_mSALBN' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

the configurations are as the following:
nginx- v1.8.0

```
upstream node {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:3001;
        server localhost:3002;
        server localhost:3003;
        server localhost:3004;
        server localhost:3005;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysite.co
        root /var/www/mysite/web;
        rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
        }
        # Deny all . files
        location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/(app|idan_dev)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index app.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 30;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 30;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        # Statics
        location /(bundles|media) {
        expires 1d;

        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }
        error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx-access.log;

        location ~ /socket.io {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://node;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_read_timeout 150;
                access_log off;
        }

}
```

on the nodejs part I approve any one (as for now, to test this specific problem)

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var sockets = [];
var request = require('request');

// these statements config express to use these modules, and only need to be run once
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/data', function(req, res) {
  // do some stuff with data sent directly to node.
});

app.listen(parseInt( process.env.port ) + 1000); // set listening a port for port for the balancer.

module.exports = app;

// run HTTP server on this port
console.log('listening to port ' + ( parseInt( process.env.port ) - 3000 ));
server.listen(process.env.port); // setting multiple ports for same file 

// allow any user to authenticate.
io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback)
{
  return callback(null, true);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
  var id = getUserId(socket);
  console.log('on connection id - ' + id);
  if( id === false) return;
  sockets[id] = socket;

  socket.on('disconnect', function()
  {
    var index = sockets.indexOf(socket);
    if (index != -1) {
      sockets.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });

});


function getUserId(socket) {
  // getting the id of the user..
  return '1';
}
```

I don't know if its related but the site itself is php based, only the socket system is nodejs based.
I'm pretty nice to nodejs and socket.io, so if there's any data missing let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: do you have cloudflare sitting in front of the site?

Comment: I've already "fixed" it by using direct ip:port instead of nginx load balance, and yes cloudflare is sitting in front of the site

Comment: unless your cloudflare is on Enterprise pricing plan, websockets are not supported.

Comment: this is no longer true as cloudflare has now released websockets.